# Probability of rolling a 1 before a 6 on a dice

Tags: probability

what is the probability that I roll a "1" on a dice before rolling a "6". I do not know how to tackle this problem. I was thinking that this is a Geometric random variable but I do not know how to solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By symmetry, the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Remark:** We could also do it the long way. We win if we roll a $1$ before we roll a $6$. This can happen in several ways.

1. We roll a $1$ immediately. The probability that happens is $\frac{1}{6}$.
2. We roll something that is neither a $1$ nor a $6$, and then roll a $1$. The probability that happens is $\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$.
3. We roll something that is neither a $1$ nor a $6$ twice, and then a $1$. The probability that happens is $\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{6}$.

Continue.

Finally, sum the infinite geometric series.